# Implementing a similar menu like MS Website

Tags: menu

Check the menu on this Microsoft site:

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/system-requirements.aspx

Check the Main menu bar, Sub menu bar and the Drop down menu bar on this site.

Does anyone know how can we implement such menu?  It there any control in ASP.NET for this?

Answer (score 1):

That is Javascript, why don't you use firebug in Firefox to check out the code for the nav bar.